# Output in Yield statement is different

Tags: scala

```
for (c <- "Hello"; i <- 0 to 1) yield (c + i).toChar
```

why the above line yield is different from the below line yield

```
for (i <- 0 to 1; c <- "Hello") yield (c + i).toChar
```

Even though `(c + i).toChar` is same for the above lines and the output should be the same but it is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The demonstrates that the order of generators is significant. (Every `<-` is a "generator".)

The 1st generator is "slower" in that it advances only after the 2nd generator completes a cycle.

The 1st generator also guides the output collection type. If it iterates through a `String` then the output is a `String`, if the output elements are still `Char`s.  If it iterates through a `Range` then the output is an `IndexedSeq[]`. (According to the [Scala docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html), `Range` is "a special case of an indexed sequence.")

Comment: Thanks. understood now.